# HTTP requests from built-in Apama runtime in Cumulocity

Tags: apama

I'm using Apama v10.3.1. I'm using the built-in Apama container of a Cumulocity installation (currently on v9.20, soon upgrading to v10.4.0), that is all I'm uploading is a monitor, not an entire Apama project. In my Apama monitor I'm executing an HTTP GET request against the Cumulocity REST API to obtain additional parameters I need for my monitor processing.

I'm following the documentation here:

http://www.apamacommunity.com/documents/10.3.1.1/apama_10.3.1.1_webhelp/apama-webhelp/#page/apama-webhelp%2Fco-ConApaAppToExtCom_httpclient_using_predefined_generic_event_definitions.html%23wwconnect_header

The problem is that following this approach requires the monitor to use the package com.softwareag.connectivity.httpclient.

However, monitors with a package definition cannot be uploaded to the built-in Apama container in Cumulocity. Cumulocity throws an error if you try to upload a monitor with a package definition. This is also documented here:

https://cumulocity.com/guides/apama/best-practices/#limitations

Now, is there any way to invoke an HTTP service from a monitor which is to be executed within the built-in Apama container in Cumulocity?

Thanks,
Mathias

Comment: Sorry, obviously I can import the required classes instead of importing the package as follows:

using com.softwareag.connectivity.httpclient.HttpTransport;
using com.softwareag.connectivity.httpclient.Request;
using com.softwareag.connectivity.httpclient.Response;

Thanks,
Mathias

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, obviously I can import the required classes instead of importing the package as follows:

```
using com.softwareag.connectivity.httpclient.HttpTransport;
using com.softwareag.connectivity.httpclient.Request;
using com.softwareag.connectivity.httpclient.Response;
```

Thanks, Mathias